# Почему нельзя использовать StreamReader вместе с NetworkStream?

Tags: c#, сокет, потоки-данных

В книге Албахари "C# 6.0 in a Nutshell" написано следующее:

> В действительности класс `StreamReader` абсолютно запрещено применять
>   вместе с `NetworkStream`, даже если вы планируете вызывать только
>   метод `ReadLine`. Причина в том, что класс StreamReader имеет буфер
>   опережающего чтения, который может привести к чтению большего
>   числа байтов, чем доступно в текущий момент, и бесконечному блокированию
>   (или до возникновения тайм-аута сокета). Другие потоки, такие
>   как `FileStream`, не страдают подобной несовместимостью с классом
>   `StreamReader`, потому что они поддерживают определенный признак
>   окончания, при достижении которого метод `Read` немедленно завершается,
>   возвращая значение `0`.

Какая ошибка, например, в этом классе?

```
public class AsyncSocket : IDisposable
{
    Socket socket;
    StreamReader sr;

    public AsyncSocket()
    {
        socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        sr = new StreamReader(new NetworkStream(socket));
    }

    // ... остальные члены убраны

    public async Task<string> ReadLineAsync()
    {
        return await sr.ReadLineAsync();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (sr != null) sr.Close();
        if (socket != null) socket.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Допустим, пришла строка "123\r\nqwe". `StreamReader` считает всю её в свой внутренний буфер при вызове `ReadLineAsync()` вернет "123". Данные из внутреннего буфера не удаляются же? При втором вызове `ReadLineAsync()` завершится, когда придет конец строки и в результатом вернется "qwe". 
Албахари пишет про бесконечное блокирование, так к нему может привести и обычный метод `Read`, если никакие данные не будут отправлены сокету.

Объясните почему нельзя использовать класс `StreamReader` вместе с `NetworkStream`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Буфер опережающего чтения" означает, что `StreamReader` попытается вычитать из потока сразу килобайт (`bufferSize`) данных. "Про запас". Это улучшает производительность в случае чтения с диска, но может приводить к непредсказуемым последствиям при чтении.

Особенность `NetworkStream.Read` в том, что он может блокироваться при чтении (в случае, если сокет еще открыт, но данных нет).

Албахари пишет о теоретической ситуации, когда

- `StreamReader` мог бы вернуть вам данные (т.к. они есть в буфере),
- но обнаружил, что в буфере есть место и решил на всякий случай дочитать побольше данных в буфер
- вызвал `NetworkStream.Read`
- `NetworkStream.Read` заблокировался

И вы оказываетесь в ситуации, когда вроде как нужные вам данные пришли, но `StreamReader` висит и не возвращает ничего, т.к. хочет еще больше данных из потока.

На практике (в текущей реализации `StreamReader` и `NetworkStream`) такая ситуация не возникает, т.к.

- `StreamReader` читает данные из входного потока только в случае, если в буфере недостаточно данных для завершения требуемой операции.
- `NetworkStream.Read` не блокируется, если хоть какие-то данные есть.

Т.е. блокировка произойдет только в случае, когда нужные данные действительно не пришли.

Но реализация — это одно, нет никаких гарантий что она не поменяется.

На самом деле проблема решается тем, что сочетание `NetworkStream` + `StreamReader`  не имеет практической ценности. `StreamReader` приспособлен для работы с чисто текстовыми данными. Например, он пытается искать в читаемом потоке преамбулу (BOM), и вообще — использует сами данные для определения концов строк, что уже дико неудобно при работе с сетью.

По сети обычно передаются смешанные данные. Например, те же строки принято передавать в виде <длина><текст>, чтобы не попадать в ловушку "непонятно сколько данных вычитали и сколько еще ждать". Для такой работы со стримами удобнее использовать `BinaryReader`.